# How to read text like notepad?

Tags: r, tabulizer

I have a PDF files and It have tables like this ( just metaphor)

```
      American | Asian | African | European | Middle
      Animals  |       | Animals | pottery  |  East
               | tree  | Flying  |  fragile | 
2010     2         6        19         12        14
2011     3         5         9          9        20
2012     9         2        14          0         1
```

When I extract this table with PDFtools or tabulizer packages, then the packages extract this line by line.

So the result for first row is

```
American Asian African European Middle \r\n Animals  Animals pottery East \r\n  tree Flying fragile \r\n
```

But what I want to is extract right this

```
American Animals Asian tree African Animals Flying European pottery fragile Middle East
```

Is there any method to extract right this?

Also by chance I noticed that when I drag and copy then paste this table to Window notepad
then the notepad reads it magically like this;

```
American Animals Asian tree African Animals Flying European pottery fragile Middle East
```

So I think make some code which automatically paste table to notepad then recopy it to R so directly put it in to some variable. I also want to know how can realize this in R coding.

Comment: Something like `x <- scan(text = 'American Asian African European Middle \r\n Animals  Animals pottery East \r\n  tree Flying fragile \r\n', what = character())`? I have tested with the string as posted, you would pass the first row of your data set.

Comment: I tried your reply and the result is the first case : 

[1] "American" "Asian"    "African"  "European" "Middle"   "Animals" 

[7] "Animals"  "pottery"  "East"     "tree"     "Flying"   "fragile"

That's what I don't want. what I mean is to change this 

[1] "American" "Animals"    "Asian"  "tree" "African"   "Animals" 

[7] "Flying"  "European"  "pottery"     "fragile"     "Middle"   "East"

Some sequence like this.

Comment: are you trying to remove the `\r\n` or are you trying to read in the data as a table?

Comment: I just want latter, read in the data as a table.